# переименовать группу файлов, почему bash ругается?

Tags: linux, bash, macos

в инете нашел как это сделать:

```
basename -s .txt *.txt | xargs -n1 -i mv {}.txt {}.sh
xargs: illegal option -- r
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]
```

на habr нашел вариант:

```
ls | sed -e "p;s/.txt/.sh/" | xargs -2 -fmv
xargs: illegal option -- 2
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]
rename 's/.txt/.sh/g' *.txt
-bash: rename: command not found
```

man rename — открывае
Что я делаю не так?
P.S. система OS X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть подозрение, что используется alias, так как опции `-r` нет в параметрах. Поэтому отлаживаемся:

## Как отлаживать в bash

Вводим в терминал

```
set -x
```

Включается режим отладки. Затем вводим вашу команду

```
basename -s .txt *.txt | xargs -n1 -i mv {}.txt {}.sh
```

Получаем примерно следующее:

```
+ xargs -- r -n1 -i mv '{}.txt' '{}.sh'
+ basename -s .txt 1.txt 25127.txt 2.txt 6815.txt
xargs: r: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

Bash подставил вместо `*.txt` реальные имена файлов. А также разобрал пайп на отдельные команды. А также показал, что именно выполняется со всеми аргументами. В этом примере я специально перед вызовом создал алиас: `alias xargs="xargs -- r"`, чтобы получить данную ошибку. Ваш код рабочий. Почему он не работает поможет выяснить `set -x` перед запуском.

Если это скрипт, то отладку можно включить непосредственно перед проблемной строкой, а выключить так: `set +x`. Или `/bin/bash -x ваш-скрипт.sh`. Или в начале скрипта поменять строчку: `#!/bin/bash -x`

## Решение проблемы

Из комментария выяснилось, что проблема есть еще такая:

`xargs: illegal option -- i`

Поэтому читаем `man xargs` и видим:

```
-i[replace-str], --replace[=replace-str] ... This option is deprecated; use -I instead.
```

Опция устарела, и в этой версии xargx (стати, какой?) похоже больше не поддерживается.

Как починить: `-i` заменить на `-I{}`:

```
basename -s .txt *.txt | xargs -n1 -I{} mv {}.txt {}.sh
```

По проблеме `xargs: illegal option -- r` в мане написано:

```
-r, --no-run-if-empty ... This option is a GNU extension.
```

Полагаю, `-r` работает в GNU/Linux и не работает в macOS

Comment: $ set -x
+ set -x
+++ git branch
++ [[ -n '' ]]
++ parse_git_branch
++ git branch --no-color
+++ parse_git_dirty
++++ git status
++++ tail -n1
+++ [[ '' != *\w\o\r\k\i\n\g\ \d\i\r\e\c\t\o\r\y\ \c\l\e\a\n* ]]
+++ echo '*'
++ sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1*/'

Comment: + basename -s .txt test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt
+ xargs -n1 -i mv '{}.txt' '{}.sh'
xargs: illegal option -- i
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]
+++ git branch
++ [[ -n '' ]]
++ parse_git_branch
++ git branch --no-color
+++ parse_git_dirty
++++ git status
++++ tail -n1
+++ [[ '' != *\w\o\r\k\i\n\g\ \d\i\r\e\c\t\o\r\y\ \c\l\e\a\n* ]]
+++ echo '*'
++ sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1*/'

Comment: @031071, обновил ответ

Comment: так работает: 
basename -s .txt *.txt | xargs -n1 -I{} mv {}.txt {}.sh
я пробовал:
basename -s .txt *.txt | xargs -n1 -I mv {}.txt {}.sh

Comment: @031071, если проблема решена, пометье ответ как решение, если решили сами - напишите ответ, если это не трудно :)

Answer (score 1):

Я предпочитаю использовать для переименования генерирацию команд `sed`'ом, POSIX-совместимый вариант будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
ls | sed -ne 's!^\(.*\)\.txt$!mv "&" "\1.sh"!p' | sh -
```

---

> Что я делаю не так?

Вероятно, бездумно копируещь код, найденный в интернете, вместо того стобы посмотреть документацию на свою систему/прочитать выводимые ошибки. По всей видимости, это основная ошибка.

> P.S. система OS X

В MacOS используется набор стандартных утилит происхождением из BSD, которые не поддерживают многочисленные расширения GNU так популярных в GNU/Linux и других более странных GNU/* системах.

> man rename — открывае

То что установлена man страница ещё не значит, что установлена сама программа.

Comment: ls | sed -ne 's!^.*\.txt$!mv "&" "\1.sh"!p' | sh - 

sed: 1: "s!^.*\.txt$!mv "&" "\1. ...": \1 not defined in the RE

Comment: @031071, моя ошибка — поправил...